Neatbeans 19. Error al ejecutar proyectos antiguos con JDK 17
Mi antiguo PC murió y al instalar las nuevas versiones de Neatbeans y JDK, los antiguos proyectos no conectan con mi base de datos SQL server.
Los errores que devuelve son estos:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4098)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
    at es.bilmanbus.booking.conexiones.Conexiones.<init>(Conexiones.java:39)
    at es.bilmanbus.booking.DAO.ConsultasBD_DAO.selectExpediciones(ConsultasBD_DAO.java:47)
    at es.bilmanbus.booking.main.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 16 more
C:\Users\BILMA\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\19\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\BILMA\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\19\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)


En Java 17 los paquetes que antes eran javax.xml.(...) ahora son jakarta.xml.(...) y no forman parte del SDK, tienes que añadirlos como dependencias: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/

Hola Pablo. Hace años que no programo nada y ya entonces tenia conocimientos reducidos. ¿Me puedes dar alguna instruccion sobre como añadirlo en netbeans?. Gracias anticipadas

Del mismo modo que tienes los drivers de SQLServer: buscando los ficheros JAR o, si usas Maven/Gradle, declarando la dependencia
